# Why does .gitignore downloads files during pull and creating conflicts when modified?

Tags: git, github

So this problem is at two fronts. One locally and one on ec2 instance where I'm trying to pull from github.

I force pushed (git push origin main -f) from local to github with all folders and files. I pulled it on server using git pull origin main. Then I added static_files/ and .env to my .gitignore locally and got it committed and git push origin main. Now I deleted static_files folder and .env from github.

So the first problem is when I now take a git pull origin main, it deletes the folder and .env.

Secondly, I modified .env and .gitignore on my server using sudo nano but even when .env is ignored it shows conflicts during git pull origin main as,

CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in .gitignore
CONFLICT (modify/delete): .env deleted in 6d0cc45a49f2faf3bbbacd and modified in HEAD. Version HEAD of .env left in tree.
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.

Comment: adding them to .ignore does not mean you cannot put them in your repo. I guess you did some kind of `git add .` at a certain point and then committed the ignored files and now they are conflicting. you should remove them from the repository (git rm; git commit)

Comment: $ git rm /.env
fatal: C:/Program Files/Git/.env: 'C:/Program Files/Git/.env' is outside reposit
ory at 'C:/Users/V/Desktop/Code/Django/yourspace'

Comment: Sorry I am missing something. did you intentionnally committed .env or not? same for .gitignore? if yes why don't you just solve your conflicts?

Comment: On my server, I resolved the conflicts in .gitignore and did git rm .env. After that I did a git pull origin main and that now has removed the .env and static_files as well. Its my first day of using github and I think its now pretty messed up. Also yes while tying to learn some basics I have committed some times. Is there a way to restart?

Comment: hard to answer making sure you wont loose all your work; you may have a look to https://learngitbranching.js.org/ to ramp up on git.

Comment: What I did this far is like first removed conflicting items in .gitignore on local. Pushed it to github main and then loaded all the stuff to server with git pull origin main. Had to resolve a small .gitignore conflict there too but all was back there. Now have added paths to local gitignore and will be pushing that remotely. It might still keep sending static files and stuff but it's private so I hope that's a temporary fix for now.

Comment: This is all quite normal in Git. The `.gitignore` file does not mean "ignore these files". There are hundreds of questions and answers about this here on StackOverflow already (because, unsurprisingly, the fact that `.gitignore` does not mean "ignore" is very confusing). You definitely need a good introduction to Git here.